# Prove or disprove: If $f \circ g$ is Monotonically increasing, then $g$ is monotonically increasing

Tags: functions

If $f\circ g$ is monotonically increasing, then $g$ is monotonically increasing.

I think it is not true but I don't have a counterexample.

Thank you.

Comment: "Monotonically" what?

Comment: Did you indeed mean the composition of the two maps, that is, first $g$, then $f$?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=g(x)=-x$ then $f(g(x))$ is monotonically increasing but $g(x)$ is monotonically decreasing.
note that any pairs of bijective monotonically decreasing $f,g$ are also counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are both continuous and assume, for contradiction, that $g$ is not monotonic (neither monotonically increasing or decreasing).  Then, you can find points $x\not=y$ such that $g(x)=g(y)$.  But then, $f\circ g(x)=f\circ g(y)$, contradicting the assumption that $f\circ g$ is monotonic.